# How to start a second X session?

Tags: xorg, x11, startx

I tried to do it with the command `startx 1`. It seemed to flicker to a different screen momentarily, but then exited. Got the following error:

```
/usr/bin/xterm: No absolute path found for shell: :1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I think you can do it with this:

```
$ startx -- :1
```

Note that you need to be on a text console. If you do this from an X session, you may not be authorized. First <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to a text console and log in there.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to switch between the X sessions (the F key numbers may vary depending on your distribution).

If you want more control you can add more options to the command like so:

```
$ startx gnome-session -- :1 vt8
```

This will start up `gnome-session` on display `:1` and run it on virtual console 8 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>).

Comment: Oh, wow. I must have just mis-copied that command. With `sudo`, it works. Thanks.

Comment: Ugh, starting an X server with sudo causes everything within the X session to start with root privileges; this even causes some applications to fail.

Comment: @Bepetersn - I was surprised that you said you needed that. What happens without it?

Comment: @Bepetersn Run this from a text console, not from an X session. On Linux, press `Ctrl+Alt+F1` first, log in, and run `startx -- :1` from the shell prompt.

Comment: @Gilles - thank you for incorporating that into the answer!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to respond @slm. If I run `startx -- :1` from an X session, the terminal appears unresponsive for a bit, then tells me: 
    `xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /var/run/gdm3/auth-for-brian-3zy5Hn/database`, and fails a bit later with `X: user not authorized to run the X server, aborting.` During this time, nothing would come up in the 8th tty as you would expect.

Comment: However, @Gilles's solution of starting the second X server from outside an X session does indeed work; thanks much!

Comment: @Bepetersn - Yeah I completely forgot to mention the Ctrl-Alt+F8 bit to run the commands. I thought you knew that since you were using `start -- :1`. Gilles was kind enough to clean up my answer. Glad it works for you now.

Comment: There must be a way to start a new X from within X. Could I ssh into localhost and start X that way? Is there a way that's less of a hack?

Comment: @SamuelDanielson - if you have a new question please ask it. You can reference this question which should help expedite things.

Comment: Did not work for me, failing with http://ix.io/BdU

Comment: @isomorphismes says permission denied when it tries. Your not authorized.

Comment: @BrianPeterson starting X session with sudo harmfull for Python users. I can't safely use pip. One more thing, firefox browser won't start

Answer (score 6):

I have found that the following way works for me:

```
sudo xinit /usr/bin/xterm  -e "su $(whoami) -c pekwm"  $* -- :1
```

What happening here?
First I start `xinit` with an `xterm`, as a parameter to that xterm I `su` to become myself. From there I start the window manager.
Only thing you need to do is minimize (not close) the `xterm`.
Probably you could tell the `xterm` to start minimized—but I have not care enough to find that out.

Also:
Replace pekwm with the session you want to login to. Look in the .dewsktop-file in /usr/share/xsessions

Edited code. Changed from my real username as in example to the output from `whoami`

Comment: On ubuntu 20.04. This, at least gives a new login dialog on CTRL+ALT+F1. But after login, I land in the existing session on ...F2, and the ...F1 goes back to the login dialog.

Comment: @user66081 I changed the command. Please try again. And read the lines I added in bottom off the edited post.

Answer (score 0):

When I start another Xorg env I switch to tty2 (Ctrl+Alt+F2), then login as root and run those commands:

```
Xorg vt8 :1 &
su - user
export DISPLAY=:1
fluxbox &
```

You might have to change back to tty2 right after Xorg has started.
And I've seen Xorg with setuid bit set so you can start Xorg without root, so check it out :)