# Start application using xinit on different tty

Tags: fedora, tty, x-server, xinit

I'm using Fedora 21, trying the following:
On tty1 is running KDE, just as normal. But to speed up my games/avoid them changing something like gamma, I want to run them on a differnt tty, starting a new X server. Some time ago, I was able to do this like this(example: winemine):

```
xinit winemine -- :1
```

This should be run from my KDE workspace. But this doesn't work, it just kinda crashes my KDE, showing only the "startup messages" on tty1. So I searched a bit about this, and came up with this:

```
xinit winemine -- :1 vt2
```

Which works, but only if it is run from tty2. This would work, but it would be very annoying to manually switch to tty2, run the command... instead of just running the application from tty1, using KDE.
Is there any way to make this possible?

THX in advance, Marius

Comment: I have been having the same problem with the Nvidia drivers, but not other video drivers. That said, [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85384/22724) suggests you need to be in a tty to run startx.

Comment: Hm, okay that's the problem I'm facing right now, because it's not very comfortable. I thought it would be enough to change "allowed_users" to anybody(sth like this, can't remember exactly right now) to avoid using a tty.